# Phonegap 3.1.0 plugins failing: error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.device.Device

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I have built an app in Phonegap 3.1.0 which works great in IOS. But when deploying to android it gives errors with plugins in Eclipse on LogCat.

```
error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.device.Device
```

and after clicking the alert "[ERROR] error initializing Cordova: Class not found" I get more errors:

```
Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager
```

I've added everything through the CLI and like I mentioned, it works in IOS. And of course I followed the Phonegap guidelines.

[image: LogCat output with "plugin" filter]

These errors are driving me nuts. I've been up and down google, and all "solutions" are not working. It all relates to previous versions where there were XML faults/errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Had a similar issue, only way to get it to work was to remove plugins and platforms, install platforms and then reinstall the plugins.

Comment: SHIT!
But I'll try it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: there's a file android.json in the plugins folder and ofthen i see it not updated correctly when adding plugins.

Comment: So yeah, it took me a while. But it worked. All is well in la la land again.

Comment: Is that the only fix? I mean you need to remove almost everything?

Comment: Hi Dreyfus,
This is what what worked for me. Deleting the complete app and rebuilding clean via cli. After that I only put the html/js back.
It's not pretty, but it'll save you a very big headache trying to find what actually is going on. But be my guest and let me know.

Comment: I can confirm with @Matt that this is also the only thing that worked for me as well.  I found in the android.json file that the "PACKAGE_NAME" was incorrect for the plugin that wasn't working.  I tried changing this to the correct path, but it didn't solve the issue.  Only deleting "Android" and everything in "Plugins" resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I faced same issue of class not found, but by checking log I realized files are not getting copied to appropriate folders so I gave full permission to project and run : cordova build,  and cordova run android, and now its working seamlessly.